# Python - Any other way to add a space between 2 concatenating strings using print() function

Tags: python-3.x

Let us take 2 strings `a` and `b` and concatenate them using `+` using print() function.

```
a = 'Hello'
b = 'World'

print(a + b, sep = ' ')
# prints HelloWorld

print(a + ' ' + b)
# prints Hello World
```

I have 2 questions:

a) Can I use sep to add a space between the concatenated strings `a` and `b`?

b) If not, then, Is there any other way to add a space between the concatenated strings `a` and `b`?

Comment: `print(a, b, sep=' ')` ?

Comment: I want to add space while concatenating the 2 strings

Comment: ...`f'{a} {b}'` ?

Comment: @jpp, I want to add space while concatenating 2 strings. Your solutions add a space between the strings, but these strings are not concatenated.

Comment: Are you sure? Try `x = f'{a} {b}'`, then `print(x)`. Looks concatenated to me. Otherwise, define "concatenated".

Comment: I want to have a space between strings joint using '+' operator.

Comment: `print(*[a]+[b])` But please don't do that. Use Python as it is supposed to be used. Don't specify the syntax you want to use, but use that syntax as it is supposed to be used. Just use: `print(a, b)`

Comment: Thanks @HielkeWalinga for your solution, I wanted to know how actually it worked i.e. `print(*[a]+[b])`. I request you to explain this as the answer of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really like to make use of the plus sign to concatenate strings with a delimiter. You can use plus to make a list first and than apply something that will delimit the arguments in the list.

```
# So, let's make the list first
str_lst = [a] + [b] # you could also do [a, b], but we wanted to make use of the plus sign.

# now we can for example pass this to print and unpack it with *. print delimits by space by default.

print(*str_list) # which is the same as print(str_list[0], str_list[1]) or print(a, b), but that would not make use of the plus sign. 

# Or you could use join the concetenate the string. 
" ".join(*str_list)
```

Okay, so hope you learned some new things today. But please don't do it like this. This is not how it meant to be done.

Comment: Thanks @HielkeWalinga for your answer, I'm new to python, so wanted to explore it further. I know there are more easier ways to do the same, but I learnt a new way of doing this.